# Record Screen video along with the audio

Tags: android

I want to implement screencast feature in my Android app, i.e. Recording the audio and the screen video at the same time and converting it to a .mp4 file.

I got to know that there are some Media Codecs inbuilt in the Android SDK, but the issue with those ones is that I will need to record video and the audio separately and then stitch both of the elements together to create a complete video.

I want to know if a library exists which can directly record both the Audio and Video without the need to stitch them later on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

this project can help you get started [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Telecine)

Comment: @Mangesh, I am not trying to record video using camera, instead I want to record video of whatever is going on the screen (along with the audio).

Comment: yeah the app  records your  screen  have a look at it

Comment: Ok, but it's support has been withdrawn by Jake, isn't it?

Comment: I am unable to fetch the app from Play store. Do you have the apk of the project?

Comment: no i don't have apk ,you can clone the repo and build it

Comment: It doesn't record the audio simultaneously.